# Is there way to create multiple turtles using a loop?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

For example:

```
import turtle

num = 1
for i in range (10):
    num = turtle.Turtle()
    num += 1
```

I want to make 10 turtles named from 1 to 10. A code like this just makes one turtle called num before kicking up an error (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Turtle' and 'int'). Is there a way to make the 10 turtles named from 1 to 10 without manually defining them all?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please share the entire error message. Have you done any research?

Comment: Yes, just store each of them in a list or dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
num = []
for i in range (10):
    num.append(turtle.Turtle())
```

?

Comment: What does this call the turtles? For example what would replace the 'abc' in this: abc.fd(30)

Comment: `num[0]`, `num[1]` etc. Seriously, if you don't know that, you should get a Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle

# Create a list of turtles
turtles = [turtle.Turtle() for _ in range(10)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of num = 1, it should be num = 0, but appending works better because num is just simply counting in this case and doesn't have a relationship with num = turtle.Turtle().